# Ember-data: How do I get an aggregated list of models in a collection on a different collection (@each not working)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to get an aggregated list of `employees`.  Each `organization` is a model that `hasMany` `employees`.

```
var Organization = DS.Model.extend({
    name:       attr('string'),
    employees: hasMany('employee', { async: true })
});
```

On my controller, I have this property.

```
employees: function(){

    var employees =[];

    this.get('organizations').forEach(function(organization){
        employees.pushObjects(organization.get('employees'));
    });

    return employees;

}.property('organizations.@each.employees.isFulfilled')
```

When I loop through these on the template, the `employees` are being loaded, I can see the api returning the data (Im using `async: true`), but the return value of `employees` is still an empty array.

It seems like I might be listening to the wrong thing on the property.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember doesn't support dependent properties multiple levels deep.

http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/

And your employees being an async property will be empty when you attempt to push in this fashion.  You'd need to move the fulfilled employees a level higher (something like this):

```
var Organization = DS.Model.extend({
    name:       attr('string'),
    employees: hasMany('employee', { async: true }),
    loadedEmployees: function(){
      return this.get('employees');
    }.property('employees.[]')
});
```

With a computed property using `loadedEmployees`

```
employees: function(){

  var employees =[];

  this.get('organizations').forEach(function(organization){
    employees.pushObjects(organization.get('loadedEmployees'));
  });

  return employees;

}.property('organizations.@each.loadedEmployees')
```